# Integral solution for Laplace equation in multiply connected domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

Let $ \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a bounded and simply connected domain with its boundary $\partial \Omega \in C^2 $, $f \in C(\partial \Omega) $ be some given function, then for
$$
\Delta u = 0 \ \textrm{in} \ \Omega, \quad  u = f \ \textrm{on} \ \partial \Omega
$$
the solution can be represented as
$$
u(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \psi(y) \ln \vert x-y \vert ds(y), \quad x \in \bar \Omega
$$
if and only if $ \psi \in C(\partial \Omega) $ solves
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} \psi(y) \ln \vert x-y \vert ds(y) = f(x), \quad x \in \partial \Omega
$$
The above proposition should be a classical result in potential theory. Could anyone recommend some reference?

Moreover, we would like to know if the condition "simply connected" can be relaxed to multiply connected?For example, from a disc to an annulus? Thanks in advance!